# Почему при спавне объекта в Юнити он не отображается, но появляется?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть несколько заданных координат и мне нужно, чтобы объект рамдомно спавнился на одной из них.
Я реализовал это так (скрины).
Все работает как бы, когда я нажимаю F объекты появляются слева, но не появляются в самой игре, только если переключаться на меню сцены, там они появляются как надо, да и когда я нажимаю F чтобы заспавнить объект, вылетает ошибка:

```
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
RandomSpawn.SpawnRandom () (at Assets/Scripts/RandomSpawn.cs:26)
RandomSpawn.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/RandomSpawn.cs:19)
```

Я погуглил, как ее решить и много чего нашел, но у меня должно быть все правильно.
Помогите пожалуйста в решении данного вопроса, ибо я не понимаю.

Мой код:

```
public Transform[] listObjects;
public GameObject Coin;
int random;
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.F)) {
        random = Random.Range(0, listObjects.Length);
        spawnRandom();
    }
}
private void SpawnRandom () {
    Instantiate(Coin, listObjects[random].position, Quaternion.idenity);
}
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код в виде текста! listObjects точно не пустой? Выведи его длину в Start

Comment: Почему имя listObject, но это массив NotLikeThis

Comment: Этот Массив точно не пустойЭтот скрипт был привязан к каждой координате, и поэтому в каждой координате он искал массив и не находил
Я отключил у каждой координаты этот скрипт и оставил только основному, куда они все привязаны
Ошибки ушли, но вся та же проблема...

Comment: Это значит дело где-то в Юнити, но я не знаю что делать

Comment: дело в 99.999999% случаев в коде а не юнити. А у начинающих в 100%. Так что разслабься и делай что советуют - выведи его длинну в старт. Кроме того выведи в консоль значение Random.Range на каждой генерации. Возможно, поймешь в чем дело.

Answer (score 1):

Нумерация массива начинается с нуля. В массиве из 5 элементов индексы элементов 0,1,2,3,4.

Строкой `random = Random.Range(0, listObjects.Length);` вы переменной random присваете значение от 0 до 5 ***включительно***! Так как в C# в отличии от некоторых других языков функция Random.Range возвращает значение от минимального включительно до максимального включительно.
Строка из документации:
`Return a random float number between min [inclusive] and max [inclusive]...`
И сама [документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)

Таким образом, чтобы не брать 5-й элемент массива (хотя последний элемент - 4-й), вы должны исправить на:

```
random = Random.Range(0, listObjects.Length - 1);
```

> P.S. Массив из 5 элементов - просто пример